# Error while deleting list item 0x80131904

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sql-server-2012

We are getting below error on production server,on development and test server its working fine.There is Application page to fill employee goals for appraisal,when user tries to save in draft they are experiencing issue that goals are deleting and not save.when we check in production log we are getting 'COMException'    ExceptionMessage: '0x80131904' .

> 01/21/2014 18:57:05.26  w3wp.exe (0x3D98)        0x29FC  VFS
>   Performance Management Syst       PMS Error            9999
>   Unexpected       Error in PMS H2 Self Evaluation   ExceptionType:
>   'SPException'   ExceptionMessage: ''   StackTrace: '   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.DeleteItem(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, Int32 lID, UInt32 dwDeleteOp, Guid&
>   pgDeleteTransactionId)       at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.DeleteCore(DeleteOp deleteOp)       at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Delete()       at
>   VFS.PMS.ApplicationPages.CommonMaster.DeleteCompetenciesDraft(Int32
>   appraisalPhaseId, String currentUser, String listName)       at
>   VFS.PMS.ApplicationPages.Layouts.H2initial.SelfEve.SaveCompetenciesDraft(Int32
>   appraisalID, Int32 appraisalPhaseId, String listName)       at
>   VFS.PMS.ApplicationPages.Layouts.H2initial.SelfEve.b_*0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__2()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)       at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>   secureCode, Object param)       at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)       at
>   VFS.PMS.ApplicationPages.Layouts.H2initial.SelfEve.btnSave_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)'   Source: 'Microsoft.SharePoint'   TargetSite:
>   'Void HandleComException(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)'
>   ------------------------------------------------------------   Inner exception:
>   ------------------------------------------------------------    ExceptionType: 'COMException'    ExceptionMessage:
>   '0x80131904'
>   StackTrace: '   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.DeleteItem(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Int32 lID, UInt32 dwDeleteOp, Guid&
>   pgDeleteTransactionId)        at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.DeleteItem(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, Int32 lID, UInt32 dwDeleteOp, Guid&
>   pgDeleteTransactionId)'    Source: ''    TargetSite: 'Void
>   DeleteItem(System.String, System.String, Int32, UInt32, System.Guid
>   ByRef)'    8f922003-389d-4edf-b75f-7e69c5818a7a

Comment: Hello Zakir DB Size is fine as i have checked its fine and also Sql is standard version.
And Error is coming only for this application site.Other application are working fine that are in different site but same site collection

Answer (score 1):

0x80131904 type of exception generally occurs from SQL Server side. It may be caused by temp DB or Content Database is out of space.

So, please go to the SQL Server, and ensure that there is enough free space for the SQL Server especially for the Content Database.

Comment: Can u please tell what is minimu space required for both . And also we have recently migrated our DB to different server. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The size depends on the usage of your web application. How much data is being stored on a daily basis. How many and what type of documents are uploaded to document libraries on daily basis or at least weekly. If you read this Microsoft article it says, 200 GB is recommended.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/05/25/sharepoint-2010-content-database-size.aspx

Comment: Hello Zakir DB Size is fine as i have checked its fine and also Sql is standard version. And Error is coming only for this application site.Other application are working fine that are in different site but in same site collection